# The difference between the edns parameters of the new and old versions of dig

Tags: dns

[test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64y0z.png)

I tested different versions of dig. Are the dig +client parameters of version 9.9.3 the same as the dig +subnet parameters of version 9.10? Is there a difference? thanks very much!

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming but besides that, please do not link images, show your data as text inside the question directly. Not as image.

Comment: Are you sure it is 9.9.3? I find no mention of `+client` in the manpage. In fact I see no mention of `+client` in any of the manpages versions...